# Visual Studio Code Weird bug, shows a not defined error from another file while defined

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, console

Something weird. A testOrder.py running in the debugger stops at some point where there is no error, but shows an error what is not an error.

See image.

[image]

What can I do to avoid this anoying thing? It happens to often.
The file is the testOrder.py file.

the code I was busy with.

```
import pprint


order = {'clientOrderId': 'KQKthPrRfLXNdfgdRhtB4e',
 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '24.96264800',
 'executedQty': '25.00000000',
 'fills': [{'commission': '0.00004822',
        'commissionAsset': 'BNB',
        'price': '0.99851000',
        'qty': '14.80000000',
        'tradeId': 2257748},
       {'commission': '0.00003323',
        'commissionAsset': 'BNB',
        'price': '0.99850000',
        'qty': '10.20000000',
        'tradeId': 2271079}],
 'orderId': 58344854,
 'orderListId': -1,
 'origQty': '25.00000000',
 'price': '0.00000000',
 'side': 'SELL',
 'status': 'FILLED',
 'symbol': 'ADAEUR',
 'timeInForce': 'GTC',
 'transactTime': 1616888830938,
 'type': 'MARKET'}


pprint.pprint(order)

def getOrderFillsStats(order):
    _dict = {}
    _price_min = 0.0
    _quantity = 0.0
    _commission = 0.0
    _fill_value = 0.0
    fills = order['fills']

    for fill in fills:
        _price_fill = float(fill['price'])
        if _price_min > _price_fill:            # get the lowest price from this order
            _price_min = _price_fill
        _quantity += float(fill['qty'])      # get the total of quantities
        _commission += float(fill['commission'])
        _fill_value += (_price_fill * float(fill['qty']) ) # get the fill part value

    _dict['price_min'] = _price_min
    _dict['quantity'] = _quantity
    _dict['commission'] = _commission
    if _quantity > 0:
       _dict['price_avg'] = _fill_value / _quantity
    else:
       _dict['price_avg'] = 0.0

    return _dict


_myDict = getOrderFillsStats(order)
pprint.pprint(_myDict)
```

The mentioned error line buyPrice = ....... is in another file in the same directory and currently running for days with no errors in a terminal/console. The perc_delta_sold_buy is defined and used for days.

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you show your code?

Comment: The problem is, that the error is every-time on a different place, but I add the code that I was working on. Bear with me, I am now maybe 35 evening hours an Python expert ;)

Answer (score 0):

When copying and pasting your code, this is what gets returned:

```
{'clientOrderId': 'KQKthPrRfLXNdfgdRhtB4e',


'cummulativeQuoteQty': '24.96264800',
 'executedQty': '25.00000000',
 'fills': [{'commission': '0.00004822',
            'commissionAsset': 'BNB',
            'price': '0.99851000',
            'qty': '14.80000000',
            'tradeId': 2257748},
           {'commission': '0.00003323',
            'commissionAsset': 'BNB',
            'price': '0.99850000',
            'qty': '10.20000000',
            'tradeId': 2271079}],
 'orderId': 58344854,
 'orderListId': -1,
 'origQty': '25.00000000',
 'price': '0.00000000',
 'side': 'SELL',
 'status': 'FILLED',
 'symbol': 'ADAEUR',
 'timeInForce': 'GTC',
 'transactTime': 1616888830938,
 'type': 'MARKET'}
{'commission': 8.145e-05,
 'price_avg': 0.99850592,
 'price_min': 0.99851,
 'quantity': 25.0}
```

Is that the output that you are looking for?

Comment: yes, thats the result ( except that the price_avg value is wrong, but that just a typo in the original code ). But why it does the weird thing, sometimes.

Comment: How are you running/ debugging this code?

Comment: Visual Studio Code f5. Then a breakpoint somewhere and it did stop at the above shown code line and not at the breakpoint.

Comment: When running it through the debugger, it seems to also be working fine, what is the version of python you are using?

Comment: I'am using 3.9. It doesn't happen very often. Is this maybe a VSC thing inside what triggers this?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, this error is occurring based on a variable in another file, try removing that file from the same folder and try it again.

Comment: I did do that, then it stops, but finally the other file will call several functions in other files in the same directory, kind using of myOwnLibWithFunctionsAndVariables.py. I would like to know what going on. Is VSC 'doing to much' what it shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Could you post the code for the other file which is causing it to return an error